# Joins gives duplicate rows, How can i filter them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In here i wont to get only one row for each "TourId", but it gives multiple rows for each  "TourId". how can i fix it? plese tell me posible ways which can improve this view.

ALTER VIEW Bill
AS

```
            SELECT  Tour.TourId,
                    Itinerary.ItineraryId,
                    Tour.StartDate,
                    Tour.EndDate,
                    DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) AS Duration,
                    Itinerary.EstTravelDist,
                    Guide.IdNo,
                    CAST(5000 * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) AS money) AS PaymentfoGuide,
                    SpecialActivity.Cost AS SpecielActivityCost,
                    VisitingPlaces.Cost AS VisitingPlaceTicketCost,
                    Tour.NumberOfPeople,
                    CAST( UnitPrice * Tour.NumberOfPeople AS money) AS CostForMeal,
                    Accommodation.Location AS Accomadation,
                    CAST(UnitPrice * NumberOfPeople * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) AS money) AS TotalAccommodationCost,
                    CAST(Itinerary.EstTravelDist * 40 AS money) AS TourPackegeCost, 
                    SpecialActivity.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople AS TotalSpecielActivityCost,
                    VisitingPlaces.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople AS  TotalVisitingPlaceTicketCost,
                    CAST(Itinerary.EstTravelDist * 40 + SpecialActivity.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople + VisitingPlaces.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople + 
                    UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) 
                    + 5000 * Tour.NumberOfPeople * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) + 
                    UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) * Tour.NumberOfPeople AS money) AS FINAL_COST

            FROM (((((((((Itinerary
            INNER JOIN SpecialActivity ON
            Itinerary.ItineraryId = SpecialActivity.ItineraryId)
            INNER JOIN VisitingPlaces ON
            VisitingPlaces.ItineraryId = Itinerary.ItineraryId)
            RIGHT JOIN Tour ON
            Tour.TourId = Itinerary.TourId)
            LEFT JOIN Guide ON
            Guide.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Vehicle ON
            Vehicle.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Accommodation ON
            Accommodation.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Participant ON
            Participant.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Person ON
            Person.IdNo = Guide.IdNo)
            INNER JOIN Contract ON 
            Contract.ItineraryId = Itinerary.ItineraryId)
```

SELECT * FROM Bill

Comment: It means `Tour` has `1:N` relationship with one or more tables.. Post sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to figure some of this out yourself.

First try changing SELECT to SELECT DISTINCT. Then you'll only get one row per TourID IF every other item in your SELECT list is unique to that ID, but if one TourID can have more than one (e.g.) SpecialActivity record, then you'll have to think a bit more:

For each item in the SELECT list that does have more than one result per TourID you need to think about what you want to display: for example you might all of the different costs for each special activity summed together. Other items you might just want the first value, or the highest, etc. Use aggregate functions in those cases, and add the rest of the fields to a GROUP BY clause at the end. A rough example might look like

```
        SELECT  Tour.TourId,
                Itinerary.ItineraryId,
                Tour.StartDate,
                Tour.EndDate,
                DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) AS Duration,
                Itinerary.EstTravelDist,
                MAX(Guide.IdNo),
                SUM(CAST(5000 * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate)) AS money) AS PaymentfoGuide,
                SUM(SpecialActivity.Cost) AS SpecialActivityCost,
                SUM(VisitingPlaces.Cost) AS VisitingPlaceTicketCost,
                Tour.NumberOfPeople,
                SUM(CAST( UnitPrice * Tour.NumberOfPeople AS money) AS CostForMeal),
                MAX(Accommodation.Location) AS Accomodation,
                SUM(CAST(UnitPrice * NumberOfPeople * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) AS money)) AS TotalAccommodationCost,
                SUM(CAST(Itinerary.EstTravelDist * 40 AS money)) AS TourPackegeCost, 
                SUM(SpecialActivity.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople) AS TotalSpecialActivityCost,
                SUM(VisitingPlaces.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople) AS  TotalVisitingPlaceTicketCost,
                SUM(CAST(Itinerary.EstTravelDist * 40 + SpecialActivity.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople + VisitingPlaces.Cost * Tour.NumberOfPeople + 
                UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) 
                + 5000 * Tour.NumberOfPeople * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) + 
                UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) * Tour.NumberOfPeople AS money)) AS FINAL_COST

        FROM (((((((((Itinerary
        INNER JOIN SpecialActivity ON
        Itinerary.ItineraryId = SpecialActivity.ItineraryId)
        INNER JOIN VisitingPlaces ON
        VisitingPlaces.ItineraryId = Itinerary.ItineraryId)
        RIGHT JOIN Tour ON
        Tour.TourId = Itinerary.TourId)
        LEFT JOIN Guide ON
        Guide.TourId = Tour.TourId)
        INNER JOIN Vehicle ON
        Vehicle.TourId = Tour.TourId)
        INNER JOIN Accommodation ON
        Accommodation.TourId = Tour.TourId)
        INNER JOIN Participant ON
        Participant.TourId = Tour.TourId)
        INNER JOIN Person ON
        Person.IdNo = Guide.IdNo)
        INNER JOIN Contract ON 
        Contract.ItineraryId = Itinerary.ItineraryId)

GROUP BY            Tour.TourId,
                    Itinerary.ItineraryId,
                    Tour.StartDate,
                    Tour.EndDate,
                    DATEDIFF(day,Tour.StartDate,Tour.EndDate) AS Duration,
                    Itinerary.EstTravelDist,
                    Tour.NumberOfPeople
```

This is making huge assumptions about the structure of your data however. It may be necessary to further break down the query into logical chunks to deal with one to many relationships in your joins. For example you might like to do your grouping and aggregating on all the tables except SpecialActivity and VisitingPlaces if those are the only 1:N relationships that are the problem, then joining those tables separately to the output of the grouped and aggregated query.

Also consider removing the participant table to simply your joins: it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: your explanation is amazing! i will try to improve this code!

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, and I can't exactly confirm this without seeing the result of the query or your database structure, you have a one to many relationship: 1 TourID may have many Itineraries, for example.

If you want, you can treat the query as a form, and then use the `DISTINCT` keyword to access data from it. Alternatively, if you know what is causing your one to many relation, you can use an aggregate (like `COUNT`) on it, and use a `GROUP BY` which is appended to the end of your query.

For reference: [Group By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), [Distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: I have tried doing like this "SELECT  DISTINCT Tour.TourId," , but it's not works!

Comment: Apologies, I meant view instead of form. Different SQL tools use different keywords.  Regardless, instead of `SELECT * FROM Bill`, try `SELECT DISTINCT Tour.TourID FROM Bill`

Comment: correction: `SELECT DISTINCT TourID FROM Bill` Though this only gets you TourID. you can, of course, select more columns, but as soon as you select a column where one TourID has many of that column, your problem will return. if you need this column you will need an aggregate and a `GROUP BY`